# DDD - User Registration and bounded Context issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, domain-driven-design, registration

i'm currently working on a WebApp / Mobile App (React) and API (node) with a domain driven design architecture and Firebase Auth (Email / Password).

Here is the application registration flow:

- A **User** come on the registration page, enter profile information, email and password, then submit it to the API. (This user is a **Coach**, but at this point it's a **User** entity in the **IAM Bounded Context**).
- The User/Account is created then he can sign in to the app with his email / password.

When this user is logged in and accessed the application, he's in the business core domain of the app, and his Entity representation is a Coach.

- Later on, this **Coach** can create **Athletes**.
- The **Athlete** will then, be able to connect on the app through the login page, with his **account created**.

The thing is, the **Athlete** entity can exists only if he has an account, so i must create first a **User** from the **IAM Bounded Context**.

I have **2 issues here**, but maybe resolving the first one will lead me to the second one's solution.

1. I don't understand the flow and can't find any example to create the User in the IAM bounded context, and the Coach with his profile in the Core BC. I need an User(IAM account) to be able to connect, but the User(AIM account) doesn't care about the profile information of the Coach.
2. Later on, i'll create an **Athlete** through the **Core BC**, do I begin with **Athlete** then end up with creating his account in **IAM BC**, or do I first create his user account then the Athlete ?

I tried to use DomainEvent like CoachCreated or UserCreated to communicate between the two bounded context, but i'm losing data in between. Here is what i've tried:
*CASE 1*

- The registration page in filled and submitted in POST to /users/register.
- In the **IAM BC**, the user account is created with email / password through a User Entity. (I'm using firebase Auth so the Auth is externalized in an AuthService, i'm not storing the password in the User or in database).
- In the **Core BC**, i have a subscription to this event to create the Coach. The problem is i don't have the registration information sent by the user to create this entity. I didn't store them in the User because they don't belong there.

*CASE 2*

- The registration page in filled and submitted in POST to /coach/register.
- In the **Core BC**, I created and store the **Coach** entity with profile data, and raise a Domain Event **CoachCreated**.
- In the **IAM BC**, I have a subscription to this event to create the **user** account. The problem is i don't have the password to create the user account, and it feels wrong, because a Coach shouldn't be created without first a user account. (I need to reference in the Coach entity, a userId to get IAM information if needed).

*CASE 3*

- I just create the user account and coach profile on the same use case. But it also feels wrong because i need to execute multiple usecase at same time, and it feels like i'm mixing bounded context which is not the right way to use DDD in my opinion.

*CASE 4*

- I stay in the **IAM Context** for the whole registration, then i have a **Coach** entity, **Athlete** entity, (do i need UserAccount entity ?) and i will have also a different **Coach / Athlete** entities in the **Core Context** ? But i feels wrong because at this moment, it's just a user registering to access the app, it's not a coach or an athlete.

It seems to be a quite common case and pretty simple, but i can't figure out how i could achieve this registration process. Any tips, solutions or advises ? Being struggling for 2 days on this, maybe i can't see clearly anymore :). Or maybe i didn't understand at all the DDD !

Thanks,

Armand

Answer (score 1):

It's not always mandatory to prevent a direct integration between BCs. The primary reason could be availability, but **IAM** is such a core service that you have more important issues if it's down.

However, I think that delaying data capture could help...

For instance, you could have the user registering as a **Coach** trough the **Core BC**. The **Coach** is created and a command to the **IAM** context is placed in an [outbox](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) queue (or an event **CoachCreated** making **IAM** a downstream client of **Core BC**).

At this point the user haven't provided a password for the account. You then inform the user he's going to receive an email to complete the registration. The **IAM** context eventually processes the command/event and sends an email to the user with a link. Once the user navigates to the link in **IAM** context, he's asked to initialize his password which completes the registration.

If you are using GUIDs then the **Core BC** could have generated it up-front to make the association and then provide the **accountId** in the message payload to be consumed by the **IAM** context. Alternatively, you may also just supply it as a correlation ID that the **IAM** context would add to it's **AccountCreated** event, which then gets consumed
by the **Core BC**.

You could also make it the other way around, where the account is created first and then once the user navigates to a page in the **Core BC** he's asked to complete his profile.

I think the key really is to segregate data entry in multiple steps. It could be as simple as a wizard on the UI where you fill out account information first, then the next step would be to complete the Core BC profile. The UI would interact with both BCs directly.   Also, for creating **Athletes** it probably could work as earlier (**Athlete created**, **IAM** notifies user by email, etc.).

Comment: I see, thanks for your solution, i'll give it a try but i'm not sure i'm able to change the front end client. But i may be able to switch the account creation using a link. Something might also help me anyway, is it wrong to dispatch Event in use cases ? For now i'm only disptching event in Aggregates because it's the example i've seen, but if i'll be able to dispatch an domain event in the use case, then i'll be able to transfer the data needed to make the account creation through in the IAM BC.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - it is an ongoing process understanding the domain and of changing the way one thinks and conceptualises the problem.

In my experience the main issue is moving away from the CRUD mentality which here it seems you're still a bit entangled in, eg. "Coach can **create** athlete". This is typical CRUD.
Perhaps "coach can **invite** an athlete to join their team", to which an athlete can **accept**, **refuse** or **forget** about it.
In this way, the events that reflect the real-world domain, which you are trying to "translate", will carry more appropriate semantics about the domain and enable you to satisfy the business rules of separate bounded contexts. Hope it helps.

So in short:

1. Coach sends the invite to an athlete
2. the link takes them to an  something like "register invited athlete"
3. check the invite code
4. register user; emit event eg.AthleteAccpetedInvitation, or UserProvisionedForInvitedAthlete, or whatever is appropriate; your user aggregate can start with any of these events;
   other interested domains can react to that event; return user ID or whatever you need for user to supply with the "account registration" payload
5. register account